# VUE - Module not found. Can´t Import Component

Tags: vue.js, path, vuex

Working with VUE/VUEX.
I want to import the Component "Popup.vue" from the file: "Tienda2.vue". But I am getting this error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/layouts/Tienda2.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/layouts/Tienda2.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/components/Popup.vuex' in 'D:\Cursos\VUE\0_proyecto\src\layouts'
```

I'm pretty sure the import path is valid, here is my folder structure:

```
|----src
     |----components
     |      |---------Popup.vue
     |
     |----layouts
           |---------Tienda2.vue
```

I have tried with *@/components/Popup.vuex*  and  *../components/Popup.vuex*. Here is my code:

***Tienda2.vue***

````
<template>
<h1>Tienda2 {{id}}</h1>
**<Popup />**
  <div class="about">
    <h4 v-for="tipo in tipoArticulo" :key="tipo.nombre">
      <div @click="$router.push({name:'TipoArticulo', params: {id:`${tipo.nombre}`}})">{{tipo.nombre}}</div>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>

<script>
import {mapState} from 'vuex'
**import Popup from '@/components/Popup.vuex'**

export default {
  components: {
        **Popup**
    },
    props:{
      id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    },
    computed: {
    ...mapState(['tipoArticulo'])
    },
    created() {
        this.$router.push({name: 'TipoArticulo', params: { id: 'Láminas' }})
    }
}
</script>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJZlE.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Hx7H.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be '.vue', not 'vuex'.

```js
import Popup from '../components/Popup.vue'
```

Comment: what a silly mistake. Resolved. Thank you